# How can i find an element by xpath text() and the second cousin of this element?

Tags: text, xpath, parent, htmlunit, nextsibling

I use Htmlunit in java. I need to find an element by text(), and i need the second cousin of this element (i think).

I tried this:

```
HtmlElement element = page.getFirstByXPath("//*[text() = \"SOMETHING\"]/parent/following-sibling/child");
System.out.println(element.asText()); // it's null
```

Update:
The html source page:

```
<tr>
    <script>
    _l('its not important')
    </script>
    <td valign="top">
        <font class="its not important">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <font class="its not important">
            SOMETHING
            <script>
                _l('its not important')
            </script>
        </font>
        <script>
            _l('its not important')
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td valign="top">
        THE INFORMATION I NEED
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: By the way, I _love_ the term cousin you used! Actually, in XPath you have parents, childs and siblings, but not really cousins. But I really do like the phrase, it makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: I try to ask this simply. I'm glad you like it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath should work:

```
//tr[td/*[contains(text(), "SOMETHING")]]/following-sibling::tr/td[@valign ="top"]
```

It will select a `<tr>` element, which does have a grandchild with the required text. Then it will select all following siblings and select the next element. Please note that I selected the correct `<td>` element basec on the valign attribute value, you might not want to do that and instead use the position, i.e. `td[2]`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//*[text() = \"SOMETHING\"]/../following-sibling::*[1]/*[1]
```

Comment: It's not worked for me. I update the question with html, please check this. Thanks!

Comment: Next time, always have an input XML. Mine was just an attempted guess based on the title of your post.