# XPath: Find Node anywhere after certain other node occured

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to find a node ANYWHERE in the HTML document after a specified other node occured. Not only in siblings and childs but also very far cousins.
This is basically a linear search through the HTML document from a certain point, which I know is somehow against the hierachicyl nature of xpath.

I need this for a page with two very similar tables where I want to address the second one.

Here is a simplified example

```
<div>
    <div>
        <title>Table1</title>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Val1</td>
            <td>Val2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <div>   
        <title>Table2</title>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>OtherVal1</td>
            <td>OtherVal2</td>  (==>This is the element I want)
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This example would of course make it ease to do

`//title[text()='Table2']/../../following-sibling::table/tbody/tr/td[2]`

(like suggested [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908876/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-xpath-text-and-the-second-cousin-of-this-element))

or maybe

```
//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

But the real document I'm working with has far more `<div>`'s and other tags. Still the most natural way to distinguish the two tables is the title.
This is why I would like to do something like this:

`//title[text()='Table2']/[parseWholeCodeAfterThis]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `following` axis:

```
//title[text()='Table2']/following::table//tr/td[2]
```

This should allow you to select the `table` which located *somewhere in DOM after `title` node with `'Table2'` text value*